# Linq to Sql: How to Fetch specific row using stored procedure and display columns data into textboxes

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq-to-SQL. I want to fetch single row from stored procedure by providing specific id and show columns data into textboxes any body have idea?

Below is my query and stored procedure:

```
var db = new dbDataContext();
var query = from emp in db.Sp_Getvalue(idget) 
            select emp;
```

and something like below I want:

```
txt1.Text = query.EMP_FNAME;
txt2.Text = query.EMP_MNAME;
txt3.Text = query.EMP_LNAME;
txt4.Text = query.EMP_EMAIL;
txt5.Text = query.EMP_DOB;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I was not getting my columns references. But I resolve my problem and comment my code in below post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var list = query.FirstOrDefault();

txt1.Text = list?.EMP_FNAME;
txt2.Text = list?.EMP_MNAME;
txt3.Text = list?.EMP_LNAME;
txt4.Text = list?.EMP_EMAIL;
txt5.Text = list?.EMP_DOB;
```

The `?` is shorthand for checking for `null`.  `FirstOrDefault()` will return the first record from your sproc or null if nothing is returned.

Comment: thanks for your time and code. your code is useful for further development but I was done using below code:

Comment: `var db = new dbDataContext();
                var query = (from emp in db.Sp_Getvalue(idget)
                             select emp).FirstOrDefault();
                txt1.Text = query.EMP_FNAME;
                txt2.Text = query.EMP_MNAME;
                txt3.Text = query.EMP_LNAME;
                txt4.Text = query.EMP_EMAIL;
                txt5.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(query.EMP_DOB).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
                txt6.Text = query.EMP_USERNAME;
                txt7.Text = query.EMP_PASSWORD;`

Comment: You aren't checking for null which is recommend when using `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Well thanks for updating my knowledge I didn't know that before.